# Как изменить картинку при уменьшении экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть задача при при уменьшении экрана на 320px изменить картинку, 
как сделать правильно 
Eсть шапка и картинка должна выводится в HTML не через css
К примеру есть такая конструкция

```css
.header {
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 position: relative;
 
}
```

```html
<header class="header" style="background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);">
  <div class="main-container">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
      <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Подумал как вариант сделать ещё один блок для мобильной версии, с другой картинкой этот скрыть и показать другой.
**Как правильно сделать?** подкиньте идею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри такой вариант тебя удовлетворит или нет:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="main-container">
        <nav>
                    <div class="logo">logo</div>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
         </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
   background: url(img/bg.jpg);
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   header {
       background: url("Ссылка на вторую фотографию");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.innerWidth <= 320) {
  document.getElementById("logo").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Yandex_logo_ru.svg/2000px-Yandex_logo_ru.svg.png";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.ro/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo">
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, однако мне нужно заменить картинку в шапке                    <header class="header" style="background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);">